# OpenGL transparency not working in C#, even with alpha blending enabled

Tags: c#, windows, opengl, transparency, alphablending

I'm trying to convert one of our application from Managed DirectX to OpenGL in C#, so it'll be compatible with Windows 8.  One critical feature we need is transparency, and for practice, I've attempted to create some transparent shapes with [NeHe lesson 2](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/your_first_polygon/13002/) C# project.  It seems that even if I add in `glEnable(GL_BLEND)` and `glColor4ub(255, 255, 255, 128)`, I don't get any transparency what-so-ever.

For this test project, I simply copied the C# project linked above, and changed 2 functions.  For `InitGL()`, I added the lines necessary (or so I'm informed) to make alpha blending work.

```
private bool InitGL()
{
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
    glClearDepth(1.0f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);

    // These are the lines I've added
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);                                         // Add alpha blending
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);          // Use this alpha function
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);                                     // Don't render the backface
    return true;                                                // Initialization Went OK
}
```

And for `DrawGLScene()`, I draw the triangles and quads with color for each vertex.

```
public bool DrawGLScene()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(-1.5f,0.0f,-6.0f);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glColor4ub(255, 0, 0, 128);                     // Transparent red
        glVertex3f( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);                  // Top
        glColor4ub(0, 255, 0, 128);                     // Transparent green
        glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);                  // Bottom Left
        glColor4ub(0, 0, 255, 128);                     // Transparent blue
        glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);                  // Bottom Right

        glColor4ub(0, 0, 255, 128);                     // Transparent red
        glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);                   // Bottom Right
        glColor4ub(0, 255, 0, 128);                     // Transparent green
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);                  // Bottom Left
        glColor4ub(255, 0, 0, 128);                     // Transparent blue
        glVertex3f(0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);                  // Top
    glEnd();
    glTranslatef(3.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor4ub(0, 255, 255, 128);                   // Transparent Cyan
        glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);                   // Top Right
        glColor4ub(255, 255, 0, 128);                   // Transparent Yellow
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);                  // Top Left
        glColor4ub(255, 255, 255, 128);                 // Transparent White
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);                 // Bottom Left
        glColor4ub(255, 0, 255, 128);                   // Transparent Magenta
        glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);                  // Bottom Right
    glEnd();
    return true;
}
```

I've tested this with Windows 8 and 7, but both don't seem to depict any transparency.  Why is that?

Comment: I haven't looked at the geometry, but maybe your depth testing is a problem here. For simple blending tests it's better it have it disabled.

Comment: Good point.  I tried changing `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);` to `glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);`, but the results were the same.

Comment: Try moving `glEnable(GL_BLEND)` and `glBlendFunc` calls to `DrawGLScene` in case any state is altered between the calls to `InitGL` and `DrawGLScene`

Comment: @GuyRT Yes, for me that solved the problem.